# built in function id behavior in multiprocessing

Tags: python, cpython

```
import multiprocessing
import random
import time
import uuid


class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = uuid.uuid4()
        self.value2 = uuid.uuid1()


def print_id():
    time.sleep(3)
    t = Test()
    print(time.time(), multiprocessing.current_process().name, id(t.value), t.value)
    time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(20):
        multiprocessing.Process(target=print_id).start()
```

In python docs, id function is commented as "CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory."

If id refers to address of object in memory, I will expect id(t.value) to have different values.
(To avoid integer pool or string pool effects, I used uuid to generate random string).

However, results running in Linux(windows Subsystem) as following

```
1573442491.7650847 Process-5 139809379339728 e26051eb-1a5e-45b2-a279-8a87d902fb5f
1573442491.76799 Process-6 139809377286352 be08771f-0592-4c6c-a17a-778f869964d1
1573442491.7683392 Process-7 139809377286352 f1281fe8-b66b-46d8-826f-1a1587d96385
1573442491.7693052 Process-10 139809377286352 6d594352-6606-4bb0-bd4f-3ff88c775fa8
1573442491.7711256 Process-8 139809377286352 0d6d1aa5-fd03-4d1f-98e8-38973aebaacb
1573442491.7724354 Process-1 139809379338768 d4978687-fb5f-4d10-bbee-bcba34229829
1573442491.772816 Process-2 139809379336848 7d264c1a-5634-4798-891d-4eb0e738079e
1573442491.7740486 Process-3 139809377286480 efa39c48-e92a-4feb-b6fc-c648485dce1f
1573442491.7740998 Process-4 139809379338896 6957c2d0-e9fa-4be1-b9fb-318f2bed51f4
1573442491.7750933 Process-9 139809377286352 acc3129e-8dfa-48a5-a652-60eb71068f07
1573442492.0212004 Process-12 139809377286352 efc229d7-abb3-4101-a73d-cacb1098a4d0
1573442492.0212717 Process-11 139809377286352 2733532b-77cc-46ff-99da-c87738711cb1
1573442492.0219014 Process-13 139809377286352 19de43bb-efc1-426b-9724-5f3546101fa3
1573442492.0264502 Process-17 139809377286352 9d894bac-c60e-40be-931d-110d08c1ed57
1573442492.02747 Process-15 139809377286352 ffb3a1d1-eb11-48d3-a2dd-d460452ee2c7
1573442492.0276544 Process-14 139809377286352 0c9a683c-8de1-46c1-8638-ffb033cef588
1573442492.028296 Process-19 139809377286352 1949a743-3092-467d-b64a-8d3f2d315c89
1573442492.0284011 Process-16 139809377286352 00c0ec39-b2e2-40bc-a3e2-0de2362c9d60
1573442492.0284972 Process-18 139809377286352 3efbf7f5-b9fa-40d4-a1d5-b4a21f462e75
1573442492.0286424 Process-20 139809377286352 cea3d24b-73e8-43e5-a121-c37995c1b029
```

It could be noted that some of process will return with same id(t.value) and different t.value .

Does id function really return the real address of memory? 
If not, what is the hidden rule of memory address mapping in python or cpython?
How should I explain the output?

Comment: Each process has its own, entirely separate memory space.  Objects having the same id in two different processes means nothing.  (Analogy: would you expect there to be any connection between page 100 in two different books?)  Repeated ids are likely to happen because all of the processes started out as copies of the original process, so the next address available for allocation was the same.